# Removing cadence workflow and activity timeout

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

I'm writing a project that uses cadence workflows (cadence client 3.6.2)
And I was watching a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI&t=1236s) by maxim fateev in 2018 that mentions that cadence workflows are virtual objects and it is better not to think of them as processes that have a start point and an endpoint as they can be always live.

```
public interface SubscriptionWorkflow {
    @WorkflowMethod
    void manageSubscription(String customerId);
    @SignalMethod
    void cancelSubscription();
    @SignalMethod    
    void updateBillingPeriodChargeAmount(int billingPeriodChargeAmount);
    @QueryMethod    
    String queryCustomerId();
    @QueryMethod        
    int queryBillingPeriodNumber();
    @QueryMethod        
    int queryBillingPeriodChargeAmount();
}
```

*This section of code is from https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/workflows/#example*

When implementing a workflow it requires to specify the *executionStartToCloseTimoutSeconds*
either by code like this

```
public interface SubscriptionWorkflow {
    @WorkflowMethod(executionStartToCloseTimoutSeconds = ...)
    void manageSubscription(String customerId);
    ...
}
```

Or dynamically like

```
WorkflowOptions options = new WorkflowOptions.Builder().setWorkflowId(...).setTaskList(...)
                .setExecutionStartToCloseTimeout(...).build();
WorkflowStub workflowStub = workflowClient.newUntypedWorkflowStub("SubscriptionWorkflow::manageSubscription",options);
workflowStub.start(...);
```

And it can also be passed from the cli

```
docker run --network=host --rm ubercadence/cli:master --do test-domain workflow start --tasklist the_default_task_list --workflow_type SubscriptionWorkflow::manageSubscription --execution_timeout 3600 --input \"id\"
```

It does seem to be possible to launch a workflow without specifying this timeout and same goes for all the activities inside the workflow.

If I wanted to the workflow in my case to actually live forever is there a way to not add a timeout? same for its activities

Is it considered a bad design to have forever living workflows in general?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your workflow is running forever because it is implementing some sort of loop.

In this case, the workflow will eventually build a history object so large it will no longer be performant, as each loop iteration is persisted and then processed.

Eventually it will hit the [configured limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341666/does-uber-cadence-framework-enforce-limits-on-the-number-of-signals-received-ove) for history events and fail.

Without knowing why you want to run a workflow forever, it's difficult to offer a solution.

You could investigate using [Workflow.continueAsNew()](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/java-client/continue-as-new/) which creates a new workflow with the same ID, but starts the history anew and then will avoid hitting any limits.

Comment: In addition to this response, we recommend limiting number of activities + child workflows to 1000 for a workflow, then call continueAsNew API. You workflow ID will stay the same but you will get a new "run". This way, you can still define the workflow timeout based on that limit but also run your workflow forever.